# Speed up the PSO algorithm using Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I've implemented a **PSO** algorithm using **PyTorch**, `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`. 
I manage to speed it up 2 times but I was expecting more than that. 
It think the steps of **checking limits** `(line 41-55)` and the **parameters update** `(line 58-72)` are the cause. There's a "GPU any" of doing that?

There's is my code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor

def fitness(x,y):
    return -torch.abs(torch.sin(x)*torch.cos(y)*torch.exp(torch.abs(1-(torch.sqrt(x**2+y**2))/(3.1415))))

def velocity(v, gxbest, pxbest, pybest, x, pop, w, c1, c2):
    return w*torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)*v + \
       c1*torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)*(pxbest - x) + \
       c2*torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)*(gxbest.expand(x.size(0)) - x)

def PSO(pop, xmax, xmin, niter, wmax, wmin, c1, c2):

    vx                 = torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)
    vy                 = torch.rand(pop).type(dtype)
    best               = np.zeros(niter)
    x                 = (xmax -  xmin)*torch.rand(pop).type(dtype) + xmin
    y                 = (xmax -  xmin)*torch.rand(pop).type(dtype) + xmin
    z                 = fitness(x,y)
    [minz, indexminz] = z.min(0)
    gxbest            = x[indexminz] 
    gybest            = y[indexminz] 
    pxbest            = x
    pybest            = y
    pzbest            = z

    for K in range(niter):
        w      = wmax - ((wmax - wmin) / niter) * (K)
        vnextx = velocity(vx, gxbest, pxbest, pybest, x, pop, w, c1, c2)
        xnext  = x + vnextx
        vnexty = velocity(vy, gxbest, pxbest, pybest, y, pop, w, c1, c2)
        ynext  = y + vnexty

        **(41)** xnext = xnext.cpu()
        ynext = ynext.cpu()
        idxmax        = (xnext > xmax) # elements that are bigger that upper limit
        idxmim        = (xnext < xmin)  # elements that are smaller that upper limit
        xnext[idxmax] = xmax
        xnext[idxmim] = xmin
        idymax        = (ynext > xmax) # elements that are bigger that upper limit
        idymim        = (ynext < xmin)  # elements that are smaller that upper limit
        ynext[idymax] = xmax
        ynext[idymim] = xmin

        xnext = xnext.cuda() 
        **(55)** ynext = ynext.cuda() 

        znext = fitness(xnext,ynext)

        **(58)**[minznext, indexminznext]  = znext.min(0)

        if (minznext[0] < minz[0]):
            minz   = minznext
            gxbest = xnext[indexminznext]
            gybest = ynext[indexminznext]

        indexpbest         = (znext < pzbest)
        pxbest[indexpbest] = xnext[indexpbest]
        pybest[indexpbest] = ynext[indexpbest]
        pzbest[indexpbest] = znext[indexpbest]
        x                  = xnext
        y                  = ynext
        vx                 = vnextx
        **(72)** vy                 = vnexty

        best[K] = minz.cpu().numpy()
    return gxbest, gybest , minz, best

def main():

    pop, xmax, xmin, niter = 10000, 10, -10, 10
    wmax = 0.9
    wmin = 0.4
    c1   = 2.05
    c2   = 2.05
    xbest, ybest, fitbest, best = PSO(pop, xmax, xmin, niter, wmax, wmin, c1, c2)
    print(xbest)
    print(ybest)
    print(fitbest)
    t = np.linspace(0,niter,niter)
    plt.plot(t, best, 'k.-')
    plt.show()

main()
```

Thank so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well Well; it's working for me by using GPU !

> 8.0557 [torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 1 (GPU 0)]
>
> 9.6666 [torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 1 (GPU 0)]
>
> -19.2107 [torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 1 (GPU 0)]

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I know it works. What I'd like to know is if there's a more efficient way of doing it.  
Did you get a goo speed up? How much?

Answer (score 0):

Besides speeding up PSO, the performance depends substantially on initialization and which variant of PSO you are using.

For initialization, I only set the particle positions randomly within the range of values, and set the initial velocities to zero, since they will be updated during the first and subsequent iterations.

Most people are now using at least Clerc's version of [constricted PSO](http://mat.uab.cat/%7Ealseda/MasterOpt/SPSO_descriptions.pdf).  It appears that since you have `wmin` and `wmax` values, that's the original PSO.

The original PSO uses:

```
w = wmax - (wmax - wmin) * (iter / numIterations)
v(j, part) = w * v(j, part) + c1 * random1 * (b(j, part) - p(j, part)) + c2 * random2 * (bg(j) - p(j, part))
If v(j, part) < vmin Then v(j, part) = vmin
If v(j, part) > vmax Then v(j, part) = vmax
```

where `j` is one of the dimensions, `part` is the current particle, `v(j, part)` is the velocity, `p(j, part)` is particle position, `c1` and `c2` are the social parameters, `random1` and `random2` are random uniform numbers, `bg(j)` is the best-global position for dimension `j`, and `vmin` and `vmax` are 0.1 and -0.1, respectively.   However, you can change `vmin` and `vmax` based on the range of each feature value.

Constricted PSO uses:

```
c1 = 2.05
c2 = 2.05
varphi = c1 + c2
kappa = 2 / Math.Abs(2 - varphi - Math.Sqrt(varphi * varphi - 4 * varphi))

v(j, part) = kappa * (p(j, part) + c1 * random1 * (p(j, part) - p(j, part)) + c2 * random2 * (bg(j) - p(j, part)))
If v(j, part) < vmin Then v(j, part) = vmin
If v(j, part) > vmax Then v(j, part) = vmax
```